# Was Eclipse Comics’ Miracleman (Marvelman) comics essentially bootleg fanfic?

Tags: alan-moore, eclipse-comics, miracleman

The ownership situation of Miracleman (Marvelman) has some questions, especially with regard to the new stories using the character which began to be published by Eclipse Comics in 1982, written by Alan Moore and Neil Gaiman.

Perhaps the best authoritative resource begins here:
https://www.comicsbeat.com/poisoned-chalice-part-15-who-owns-marvelman-part-i/?amp

But the elusive question is this, did the Dez Skinn (Warrior, Pacific, Eclipse, et. al.) comics violate or essentially violate copyright when it first published new Miracleman (Marvelman) stories? Has it been established Dez Skinn owned no right or license to use the character?

Looking for factual evidence.

Comment: I suspect that the answer to this is *"it's messy and no-one's really made any effort to untangle it, since Marvel would just sue the pants of anyone who made a competing claim"*